# How to store questions and generate & list

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append

I m trying to write a code where the user is asked  whether to store/add questions or list questions. If the user selects add, they write and store the question. Then when they select list, the question/s is shown. The problem for  me is when i add a question to the previous questions added, then choose to list the questions it does not print both questions, only prints the latest one added.

Why is this? is it cause of a BREAK function terminating the loop?

thanks

if choice == 'a'

l = []

```
    while True:

        name =(input('enter'))


        l.append (name)

                break
if choice == 'l':
    print (l)
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Where's your code?

Comment: haha knew i missed something!!

Comment: Unless you've missed some lines of code, that would only really work with adding one question. If you're literally running the code multiple times to add multiple questions, then each time you run it, the list is being reset :p

Comment: yea i think thats it! how do i make it not reset :/

Comment: Don't reset the list :P   Just check it exists, and don't do anything if it does :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
while raw_input("Do you have more questions?") is not "No":
    list.append(raw_input("Enter your next question"))

..continue the program
```